# javascript not nested function scope widening

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function foo(b)
{
    return cool
    (
        function(x)
        {
            if(x)
            {
                b(x);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

where `cool` is a function that takes in a function. This code works well enough. How can I make this work though?

```
function bar(x)
{
    if(x)
    {
        b(x);
    }
}
function foo(b)
{
    return cool(bar);
}
```

I want to do this because `bar` is a frequently used function from functions that are like `foo`. Is there any way to open up the scope further so that `bar` can see `b` from `foo`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the `cool` function. Oh well it was worth asking.

Comment: Ah, I misread the code, please disregard that. I thought you were returning a function called `cool`. Take a look at Daniel's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `bar` in a function that takes `b` as an argument: i.e.

```
function baz(b)
{
    return function(x){
        if(x)
        {
            b(x);
        }
    }
}

function foo(b)
{
    return cool(baz(b));
}
```